# Making Kinetic Text animations

Tags: animation

I know [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1aHCCDki1y4) is called Kinetic Text, but I don't imagine one does this in powerpoint. What tools would I need to learn to get this done? I'd love if they were open source or low cost.

Comment: A Google search for "Kinetic Typography Tutorial" turns up hundreds of results. Some using Flash, others After Effects. You could also create the video portion with Illustrator/Photoshop and audio with something else and merge them.

Comment: Yeah, go for Flash or After Effects.

Answer (score 1):

A great solution that I used awhile ago for a project was Adobe After Effects.  At the time I was using CS4 but when I needed to watch tutorials I would go to [You Tube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=after%20effects%20kinetic%20tutorial&oq=after%20effects%20kinetic%20tut&gs_l=youtube.3.0.0j0i5.22789.23667.0.25757.4.4.0.0.0.0.72.242.4.4.0...0.0...1ac.1.d-aaU9pGQUs) and search for some.  Just know for a really good quality minute video can take months to complete.

[This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y4sOfO8Ei1g) video I loved when I was looking at doing one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use adobe after effects. It is easy to learn. Try with the [lynda](http://www.lynda.com/) tutorials, or look for videos on youtube.

Music/sound is a different story. I have not seen one kinetic typography that doesn't have a good harmony between its audio and video and their message.